# How to compare 2 lists are and able to list uncommon values

Tags: python, list, listview

I have been working on comparing 2 list and trying to list uncommon value

a = ['101,102,201,202,301,305,405,500']
b = ['101,201,202,301,405,600']

I want to compare list b with list a and list uncommon values

Code which i was trying as below

for x in a:
for y in b:
if x != y:
print x

Comment: `print(['101,122,133,145,150,222,200'][0].split(','))`

Comment: ```l = [ int(j) for i in x for j in i.split(',')]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this code

```
array = ['101,122,133,145,150,222,200'][0].split(',')
print(array)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.split()` for your required output.

```
rlist = ['101,122,133,145,150,222,200']


reqlist = []
for _ in rlist:
    nlist = _.split(',')
    reqlist.append(nlist)

print(reqlist)
```

This prints

```
[['101', '122', '133', '145', '150', '222', '200']]
```

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the elements in string format you can use [str.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to to define a delimiter and generate a list based on substrings around it:

```py
list = ['101,122,133,145,150,222,200']
list[0].split(",")
```

To obtain the numbers in int format, you may cast them. This can be achieved by [iterating](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) the previous list, creating a [new int object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) and  adding it to a new list.

```py
int_list = []
for x in list[0].split(","):
   number = int(x)
   int_list.append(number)
```

Or more succintly with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.0.html#list-comprehensions):

```py
list = ['101,122,133,145,150,222,200']
int_list = [int(x) for x in list[0].split(",")]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the split() function which take a separator as an argument i.e. ',' and returns the list of values separated.

```
l = ['101,122,133,145,150,222,200']
new_list =l[0].split(',')
>>> ['101', '122', '133', '145', '150', '222', '200']
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Answer (score 1):

For the list of integers you could do this:

```
a = ['101,122,133,145,150,222,200']
b = list(map(int, a[0].split(',')))
print(b)
```

**Output:**

```
[101, 122, 133, 145, 150, 222, 200]
```

Answer (score 1):

Go through each character of the string and form groups of digits.

Assumed string never end with a `","`.

```
data = ['101,122,133,145,150,222,200']
string = data[0]

lst = []
tmp = ''                      # group of digits
for char in string:
    if char.isdigit():
        tmp += char           # update
    else:
        lst.append(int(tmp))
        tmp = ''              # reset

# last update - assumed string never end with ,
lst.append(int(tmp))

print(lst)
```